# How to center a text in canvas vertically

Tags: android, canvas, layout

I managed to center a text horizontaly with Align.CENTER.
But it doesn't center the text vertically .

```
paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
canvas.drawText(text, fx, fy, paint);
```

How to center the text vertically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Align.CENTER` is for horizontal alignment. If you want to center vertically, you need to find the maximum height for the text and then position vertically within canvas by translating vertically using `canvas.translate`

Comment: Thanks I feared this. Ill try.

Answer (score 2):

```
 StaticLayout yourLayout = new StaticLayout(text, mTextPaint,
            canvas.getWidth(), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            false);
 canvas.translate((canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (yourLayout.getWidth() / 2), (canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((yourLayout.getHeight() / 2)));
```

This work for me.

Comment: Thanks fopr helping. I am adding lots of text. So I guess its not performant.

Comment: `StaticLayout yourLayout = new StaticLayout(text, mTextPaint,canvas.getWidth(),Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f,false);`

Create your staticLayout before onDraw and have it as a field and then invalidate. Usually this not costly irrespective of the number of the text. You can update the layout and then invalidate whenever you want.